# I am trying to figure out how to read a text file into an array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I'm trying to create a program in vb.net (forms) to process data from a UVvis spectrometer.

The txt file output looks as following.

```
"180809_QuartzRefTrans.spc - RawData"
"Wavelength nm.","T%"
400.00,90.822
401.00,90.800
402.00,90.823
403.00,90.811
404.00,90.803
405.00,90.804
406.00,90.816
407.00,90.811
408.00,90.833
409.00,90.837
410.00,90.847
411.00,90.827
412.00,90.839
413.00,90.851
414.00,90.828
415.00,90.879
416.00,90.846
```

and so on.

What I am trying to do is read the data it into an array so I can manipulate the columns. I need to be able to skip the first two lines so that all I have is numerical data. I also need it to sort the array from lowest to highest (wavelengths). Sometimes we run from 800->200 nm then accidentally put in 200->800 nm

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1
Public Class RefTrans
    Public Property Wavelength As Double
    Public Property Transpercent As Double
End Class
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strtext As String

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text Files"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    strtext = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(strtext)
    Label1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(strtext)

    Dim line1 As String
    Dim output1 As New ArrayList
    Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(strtext)
        sr.ReadLine()
        sr.ReadLine()
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            line1 = sr.ReadLine()
            output1.Add(line1)
        Loop
    End Using

    If strtext <> "" Then
        Dim SR As New StreamReader(strtext)
        SR.ReadLine()
        Do Until SR.EndOfStream
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text & SR.ReadLine & vbCrLf

        Loop
        SR.Close()
    End If

    Dim data1 = IO.File.ReadLines(strtext).
    Skip(2).
    Select(Function(line)
               Dim parts = line.Split(","c)

               Return New RefTrans With {.Wavelength = CDbl(parts(0)),
                                         .Transpercent = CDbl(parts(1))}
           End Function).
    ToArray() = line.Split(","c)

End Sub    
End Class
```

Comment: Where is the code showing what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow so I thought there was an extra step where I put the code in.

Comment: [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_)` is all you need really.  Avoid `ArrayList` as it is all but deprecated

Comment: I'm very new to vb.net. is there a way to skip the first two lines?

Comment: dim mylineslist as new array

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will get you an array of `Tuple(Of Double, Double)`:

```
Dim data = IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).
                   Skip(2).
                   Select(Function(line)
                              Dim parts = line.Split(","c)

                              Return Tuple.Create(CDbl(parts(0)), CDbl(parts(1)))
                          End Function).
                   ToArray()
```

The `IO.File.ReadLines` method will read the lines of the file.  Where the `ReadAllLines` method reads the entire file and then returns the lines as a `String` array, the `ReadLines` method exposes the lines of the file as an enumerable list and the lines only get read from the file as you use them.  Particularly for big files, `ReadLines` is more efficient than `ReadAllLines` because it does create an intermediate array first that you don't actually want.

The `Skip` method allows you to access the items in a list starting at a particular index.  In the case of reading a file, you need to read every line regardless but call `Skip(2)` on the result of `File.ReadLines` means that the first two lines of the file will be discarded after reading and any subsequent processing will only but done on lines from the third.

The `Select` method is basically a transformation.  It says create an output list containing an item for every item in the input list where the output item is the result of a transformation of the input item.  The transformation is defined by the function you provide.  In this case, a line from the file is the input and the transformation is to split that line on the comma, convert the two substrings to `Double` values and then create a `Tuple` containing those two `Double` values.

The `ToArray` method takes any enumerable list, i.e. any object that implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`, and returns an array containing the items from that list.  In this case, `Select` returns an `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Double, Double))` so `ToArray` returns a `Tuple(Of Double, Double)` array.

If you wanted to write that all out long-hand then it would look like this:

```
'Get all the lines of the file.
Dim step1 As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)

'Skip the first two lines.
Dim step2 As IEnumerable(Of String) = step1.Skip(2)

'Split each line into two substrings.
Dim step3 As IEnumerable(Of String()) = step2.Select(Function(line) line.Split(","c))

'Convert substrings to numbers and combine.
Dim step4 As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Double, Double)) = step3.Select(Function(parts) Tuple.Create(CDbl(parts(0)), CDbl(parts(1))))

'Create an array of Tuples.
Dim data As Tuple(Of Double, Double)() = step4.ToArray()
```

A `Tuple` is basically a general-purpose object for grouping values together.  You can use a `Tuple` for one-off cases rather than defining your own class.  You may prefer to define your own class in all cases though, and you should define your own class where you will use the data extensively.  In this case, your own class might look like this:

```
Public Class RefTrans
    Public Property Wavelength As Double
    Public Property TransPercent As Double
End Class
```

and the code would then become:

```
Dim data = IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).
                   Skip(2).
                   Select(Function(line)
                              Dim parts = line.Split(","c)

                              Return New RefTrans With {.Wavelength = CDbl(parts(0)),
                                                        .TransPercent = CDbl(parts(1))}
                          End Function).
                   ToArray()
```

In that case, you have properties `Wavelength` and `TransPercent` on each element of your array.  If you use `Tuples` then the properties have the generic names `Item1` and `Item2`.

Once you have the array, you can use any appropriate overload of `Array.Sort` to do the sorting, e.g.

```
Array.Sort(data, Function(d1, d2) d1.Item1.CompareTo(d2.Item1))
```

That will sort the `Tuples` by comparing their `Item1` properties, which contain the wavelength values.  If you're using your own class then obviously you specify your own property, e.g. the `Wavelength` property in the `RefTrans` class I showed.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's a blog article lol. Great _comprehensive_ answer!

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Sorry, I added it into the posting.

Comment: @CWatts You did include the code but you didn't say what's wrong with it! Also, you don't have to include everything, only the relevant part along with the errors (if any).

Comment: I can't get openfiledialog to work with Dim data = IO.File.ReadLines(openfiledialog.FileName).

I am trying to get it to where I can use openfiledialog to select my txt file then use readlines to extract the array

Comment: @CWatts You're missing a dot `.` at the end of that line. It's supposed to be `File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(....`. In jmcilhinney's code, he breaks it into multiple lines for better readability _(which you should follow)_. Also, why are you reading the file twice? If you're going to use `ReadLines()` there's no need for the StreamReader.

Comment: I see it now. I think I may have it. I just have to run it step by step now to make sure.

Comment: Remove what's after the equal sign in `ToArray() = line.Split(","c)`; that's a typo, I believe. You really need to learn how to debug your code and _read_ the error messages. I'm not sure what error you have left but there was a missing bracket in jmcilhinney's code and I just fixed it so you might want to reflect that in your code. The missing bracket was in `CDbl(parts(0))`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, thanks for the correction. I typed that all directly rather than copy and paste from an IDE, so I apologise for the mistake.

Comment: @CWatts, you should basically just copy the first and last code snippets from my post and then edit the part(s) you need to.  Probably the only change you'd potentially need to make is replace `filePath` with something.  If you actually declare a `filePath` variable and assign the file path to it, you wouldn't even need to make that change.  Once you've done that, you will have read the file and have a sorted array of the content.  Any other code you may have for reading the file or sorting the data can thus be discarded.